# Understanding Firefox' Autocompletion Popup

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I build my own Richlist-Suggest-Popup for the `URLBar` along the lines of Mozilla.

When reading [their Source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/toolkit/content/widgets/autocomplete.xml#1062) I don't understand how they simply do a `setAttribute('image', image)` as a [`richlistitem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/richlistitem) actually doesn't support this attribute.

As far as I know the `richlistitem` DOM is supposed to look the following:

```
richlistitem.autocomplete-richlistitem
  vbox
    hbox
      image.ac-site-icon
      label
```

Generating this on my own almost works, but I'm kind of sure that this is the wrong way.

Could anyone explain either how Mozilla provides this feature or show me an example how one would achieve the behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622/) and [Inspect Context](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3276/). Using these, you can see that there are a number of different [XBL bindings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL) for those list items, and one of them must be the one that lets you add an image using an `image` attribute. I hope this helps!